# Latex - how to add the name and reference of the image on the titlepage in list of figures

Tags: latex

I'm writing my thesis in latex and can not find a way to include the picture I have on my titlepage in my list of figures.

I'm writing in the report class. Is there an easy way to add this manually?

So I write in the report class and my title def. looks loke this (preamble of the document) and within the document only with the \maketitle command:

```
\title{\vspace{-5ex}{XY}\vspace{2ex}
    {\includegraphics[angle=270,origin=c,scale=0.5]{good.pdf}}\vspace{-5ex}
    {\large Department of XY, University of XY}\vspace{-2ex}
}
\author{Bachelor thesis submitted by XY\\ Supervision:
Dr XY, Prof. XY}\vspace{-2ex}
\date{August 2018}
```

Comment: The answer would depend on how you create your title page. What class do you use for your thesis? What do you want the entry in the LoF to look like (since there's no page number associated with the title, nor a figure number)?

Comment: So I write in the report class and just edited my post with a MWE, maybe that helps to understand.I only want in the LoF the first entry to be sthn like: Titlepage image by XY (2017)

Comment: For reference, a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and allows the reader to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. It does not include `good.pdf`, but something like `example-image`, since that's available in all distributions.